# Azure Resource Manager - Get publish username and password of an AzureWebApp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I can get the publish settings use the following method:

```
$website = Get-AzureWebSite -Name $webSiteName

$websitePreProd = ($website | ?{ $_.Name -like "*Preprod)" })

$siteProperties = $websitePreProd.SiteProperties.Properties

$url = ($siteProperties | ?{ $_.Name -eq "RepositoryURI" }).Value.ToString() + "/MsDeploy.axd"

$userName = ($siteProperties | ?{ $_.Name -eq "PublishingUsername" }).Value

$pw = ($siteProperties | ?{ $_.Name -eq "PublishingPassword" }).Value
```

But ideally I want to use ARM via:

```
$existingSlot = Get-AzureWebApp -Name $websiteName -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Slot "PreProd" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

How do I get URL, username and password using ARM?

Comment: Does your issue got resolved?

Answer (score 6):

@juvchan's answer will work. Here in an alternative for completeness:

```
$res = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <RG name> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName <sitename>/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
$userName = $res.Properties.PublishingUserName
$pwd = $res.Properties.PublishingPassword
```

Comment: This Code snippet is helpful. Thanks to @[DavidEbbo}(https://stackoverflow.com/users/111888/david-ebbo)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the simple script below to solve your problem.
 I assume you are trying to get the **MS-Deploy** publish profile.

Note: You should install the latest Azure PowerShell to be able to use the new Azure RM commands.

```
$webAppSlot = Get-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName <Res-Grp-Name> -Name <webAppName> -Slot <slotName>  

$pp = Get-AzureRMWebAppSlotPublishingProfile -WebApp $webAppSlot -OutputFile <OutputFileFullPathName>

[xml]$ppXml = Get-Content <OutputFileFullPathName>

# MSDeploy Publish Profile
$publishUrl = $ppXml.publishData.FirstChild.publishUrl
$userName = $ppXml.publishData.FirstChild.userName
$userPWD = $ppXml.publishData.FirstChild.userPWD
```